# Class using generic in the exception "throws" and have a List<String> param doesn't compile

Tags: java, generics

I don't understand why the classB doesn't compile:

```
interface Interface {
  <T extends Exception>void method(List<String> list) throws T;
}

// It compile but there is a warning (I understand why)
class ClassA implements Interface {
  public void method(List list) throws Exception{}
}

// This class don't compile (I don't get why)
class ClassB implements Interface {
  public void method(List<String> list) throws Exception{}
}
```

The compiler error message in the ClassB:

> The method method_1(List) of type ClassB has the same erasure
>   as method_1(List) of type Interface but does not override
>   it

Or maybe the question is why ClassA compile.

Why the < String > make the difference?

Comment: Change method in `ClassA` to use `List<String>` as the parameter type, not the *raw* `List`, which is what the warning is telling you too.

Comment: Your question should actually be why the method in ClassA compiles fine. ClassB clearly doesn't implement the method from the interface properly, You cannot throw `Exception` when you are supposed to be throwing `T`.

Comment: @Andreas The ClassA it is OK, my problem is the ClassB, please try to compile the ClassB

Comment: @Codebender Maybe, I don't know. In any case, please explain me the difference between A and B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's cover `ClassB` first.

Type arguments to a method is resolved by the *caller* of the method. It cannot be resolved by overrides in a subclass.

There are two ways to make `ClassB` work. You can add the type argument there too.<sup>1</sup>

```
class ClassB implements Interface {
    public <T extends Exception> void method(List<String> list) throws T{}
}
```

Or you can move the type argument up to the interface, so the subclass can decide.

```
interface Interface<T extends Exception> {
    void method(List<String> list) throws T;
}
class ClassB implements Interface<Exception> {
    public void method(List<String> list) throws Exception {}
}
```

---

As for why `ClassA` work, it's because of the raw type in the argument. When you use a raw type, *everything* becomes raw, which means that when compiling `ClassA`, `Interface` looks like this raw type.

```
interface Interface {
    void method(List list) throws Exception;
}
```

It is done that way for backwards compatibility. See [JLS 4.8 Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) :

> The superclasses (respectively, superinterfaces) of a raw type are the erasures of the superclasses (superinterfaces) of any of its parameterized invocations.

It goes on to say:

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. **The use of raw types** in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language **is strongly discouraged**. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.

---

<sup>1</sup> I was actually wondering how the *caller* could resolve `T`, i.e. how the compiler would infer what `T` is, given that nothing in a method call would indicate the valid exceptions.

According to the Eclipse compiler, when you write the following, `T` gets resolved as `RuntimeException`.

```
new ClassB().method(null);
```

You can override that by explicitly giving the type, e.g. this will make the method throw a `ParseException`.

```
new ClassB().<ParseException>method(null);
```

**Follow-up**

The inferred `T` is `RuntimeException` in Java 8. Without a catch statement, I get the following errors on earlier versions of Java:

```
1.5.0_22: unreported exception T; must be caught or declared to be thrown
1.6.0_45: unreported exception T; must be caught or declared to be thrown
1.7.0_79: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Java 8 dedicated an entire chapter to [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html), and it says:

> if the bound set contains `throws` α<sub>i</sub>, and the proper upper bounds of α<sub>i</sub> are, at most, `Exception`, `Throwable`, and `Object`, then T<sub>i</sub> = `RuntimeException`.

Comment: I read your explanation. I have some doubts :

1) Because I don't have a catch in my code, the compiler assume it is a RuntimeException?
2) "Type arguments to a method is resolved by the caller of the method" Then why ClassA compile? I clearly resolved the argument.
3) "When you use a raw type, everything becomes raw" , do you mean if I use at least 1 raw parameter, the function is more flexible and allow me to change the exception?

Comment: 1) No, it is not the lack of a `try-catch` statement. Read the last part: Java 8 *defines* that it is `RuntimeException`. 2) I already answered why `ClassA` compiles, in the middle section. 3) No, using raw triggers backwards compatible mode, "erasing" all generics.